# + sign isn't getting stored in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, angular, laravel

i am using Laravel and Angular. I have a an input field for phone number where + is mandatory. But + sign isn't getting stored in database.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="mobilenumber"><i class="zmdi zmdi-phone p-3"></i></label>
   <input type="number" formControlName="phone_number" class="form-control" name="phone" id="mobilenumber" placeholder="Phone number" required="" control-id="ControlID-4">
</div>

phone_number: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
```

Laravel Backend Code

```
public function CustomerRegister()

    {

        $inputs = $this->request->all();

        $v = Validator::make($inputs, [

            'email' => 'required|string|max:50',

            'password' => 'required|confirmed',

            'password_confirmation' => 'required',

            'first_name' => 'nullable|string|max:100',

            'last_name' => 'nullable|string|max:100',

            'phone_number' => 'nullable|max:15',

            'postcode' => 'nullable|string|max:15',

            'abn' => 'nullable|string|max:15',

            'state' => 'nullable|string|max:15',

        ]);
```

Phone Number datatype in database is varchar(50) and collation is utf8_general_ci

Comment: The type of your input tag is number. Therefore, the + symbol is not allowed. I suggest you change it to "text"

Comment: but with text, it will allow alphabets also. If i select text, then how to restrict alphabets?

Comment: Does every number start with a + ? If so just append it before inserting into database

Comment: yes +  is mandatory. Every number must start with +

Comment: Phone numbers can include non-digit symbols, including `+`, `-`, `(`, `)`, etc. I suggest you store them in a `VARCHAR` column, instead of an  `INTEGER` column. Phone numbers, are not really numbers.

Comment: @Aliakbar use type="tel" maybe?

Comment: Telephone "numbers" **ARE NOT** numbers in the mathematical / programing sense to begin with. `type="number"` is the absolutely wrong choice for such inputs fields to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the phone number in a `VARCHAR` column (text), and you can enforce the valid pattern using a regular expression. For example:

```
create table t (
  phone varchar(20) 
  check(phone regexp '[0-9\+\-]+')
);
```

See examples on how it accepts and rejects values at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf651d042fc6030228264982fd81860f).

**Note**: The regular expression pattern above is just an example that accepts digits, plus signs, and dashes (in any order). You can modify the pattern as needed to tailor it to your specific needs.

Comment: this constraint checks that phone has at least one 0-9 digit or + or -.  use `check(phone regexp '^[0-9]\+\-]+$')` to check that it *only* has those (and is not empty)

Comment: @ysth You are absolutey right. Thank you for the comment.